# How to determine a thread impersonation level

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I'm debugging a thread impersonating a currently logged on user in a Windows service process running under `SYSTEM` account. How could I determine the current impersonation level (as in whether *impersonation* or *delegation* was used) either programmatically, or using Visual Studio debugger or other tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way is via Visual Studio [`$user` pseudo variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd252945.aspx).